# In MongoDB, is 'users' a default collection?

Tags: mongodb

So I've been learning MEAN through the book 'Mean Machine' and in one of their examples we connect to a db to store user info while creating our RESTful api. Now, every time that we save the user info it gets stored in a collection named 'users' even though no where in the code does it explicitly save to a users collection. Also, when I just create an empty db it does not have the 'users' collection. So, is there something that I'm missing here? Or is 'users' a default collection in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection creation in Mongo is *implicit*. You can simply pretend the collection exists in your code, it will be actually created as necessary. This is keeping in line with the *schema-less* philosophy: you do not need to declare *anything* in advance, neither the names of your databases or collections nor the data structure of the documents you're going to store within them.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#collections.

Comment: I do understand that part, I'm just not understanding where the collection 'users' came from if no where in my code was it declared.

Comment: Well, somewhere you have `db.users.insert(...)`. *That's* where you declare `users`, wherever you do `db.users`.

Comment: Hmm, I will go through everything again but this is odd. Thanks for answering that users is NOT a default collection.

Comment: So I figured out what the issue was, mongoose adds an 's' to the end of 'users'. It was even "smart" enough to add an 'es' to the end of 'userx' to make 'userxes'!